# Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace

Tags: xml-sitemap

Little help about the issue, I get after adding the sitemap into google webmaster.

I get this error in the google webmaster

**Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace**

Here is the sitemap code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>https://domain123.com/</loc>
<lastmod>2020-02-10T06:35:59Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
</urlset>
```

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Sorry John.  I ll repost over there.  Appreciate the reply.